# Ruby and Rails conditional (value is null OR some value)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, conditional-statements

I'm using Ruby 2.4 and rails 5.1.7

I want to assign variable value with conditional if plan x = plan x OR plan is null.

For example, my original table will return these results:

```
plan       term     hours
A          4         60
(nul)      2         60
(nul)      3         60
B          5         60
A          6         60
```

And I need result to be like this:

```
plan       term     hours
A          2         60
A          3         60
A          6         60
B          2         60
B          3         60
B          5         60
```

Can I use something like `plan || plan.blank?` for this?

```
     courses.each do |course|
        if course.code.any?
          curriculum = course.code.find_by(code: code)
          next if code.blank?
          term = terms.find_by(order: term.to_i)
          plan = Plan.find_by(course: course, title: plan_title)
          Hour.find_or_create_by(
            term: term,
            hours: hours,
            plan: plan || plan.blank?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could is another query syntax and be explicit:

```
Hour.find_by(term: term, hours: hours, plan_id: [plan.id, nil])
```

Note that I change the query to `find_by` because `find_or_create_by` does not really make sense when an attribute can have two starts (`plan` or be `nil`). What value should the new instance have (`plan` or be `nil`)?

That said I would write that line as:

```
Hour.find_by(term: term, hours: hours, plan_id: [plan.id, nil]) ||
  Hour.create(term: term, hours: hours, plan: plan)
```

Comment: I think you n eed to change the syntax for `plan` to `plan_id` in the string and `plan.id` in the `Hash`. That being said `Hour.find_by(term: term, hours: hours, plan_id: [nil,plan.id])` will work

Comment: @engineersmnky: Great idea, that is much better.